# How can I call a specific function in my controller

Tags: function, symfony, controller, prestashop, smarty

I'm trying to create a module.

On my Dashboard I have a table with all my elements in my database, but, I don't know how I can set a function present in my controller in my smarty template.

Example of my function in my AdminController and who extends ModuleAdminController

```
public function deleteAction($id)
{
  //here my logic
}
```

In smarty how can I set my link to redirect to my function?

```
<a href="/* HERE WHAT CAN I SET ? */">Delete</a>
```

Comment: No one have an idea ?

Comment: May you post your admin controller and dbclass (objectModel extended) of your module?

Comment: I haven't create a dbclass. Do you think i can use entity manager for hydrate them ?

Comment: You have to follow PrestaShop standards. If you use "helper" on adminController and create objectModel for your table, then PrestaShop performs removal and addition operations without any additional codes.

Comment: Thanks for this informations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set your method with public static scope and then call it from you tpl. Something like

```
public static function deleteAction($id)
{
    //do semething here
}
```

and then call it from tpl like

```
<a href="{YourClassName::deleteAction('id_here')}">Delete</a>
```

But be aware that it would work only from related tpl but not everywhere

Comment: Thanks i will try tomorow and go back for give an answer

Comment: For my test i have set my function with just

echo "this is a test with the id + $id";

When i hover my link, i see in the bottom url my sentence. But when i click, nothing appening. Just a reload to go to the dashboard

Comment: You need to pass some URL instead of that text you have put into your method. But I have no idea what URL you struggling to get.

Comment: i have read "href="{AdminShowPartnersController::testAction('1')}""
And my function must say : " echo "You are in the controller with the id : + $id ";"

Comment: If you want to get any result on your front-end you need to use return statement in your method. What do you get now?

Comment: With a return it's the same... That redirect me on the dashboard but nothing appears :/

Comment: I cannot understand what do you get as the result in your method. What do you get in your "href" parameter? Do you get your return text?

Comment: No, i haven't my return text. When i hover my link i see the content of my return in the bottom url. But when i click. Nothing happening. Just redirect to my dashboard.

Comment: What do you mean "bottom URL"? Can you inspect your HTML and check out a "href" parameter of your link? I can bet that you have your return text there. And that means that your function works correctly. But if you want to get some URL instead of your sample code you need to determine it and return as the result.

Comment: yes i have my result in the href

`<a style="margin-right:5px" class="btn btn-danger" href="l'id c'est +1">Delete</a>`

Comment: You can rate the answer by clicking a top-directed arrow and accept by clicking a button related with it somewhere after your question(don't remember where exactly)